# "value == var" versus "var == value"

Tags: javascript, if-statement

At many places, I've seen developers doing `value == var` comparisons, like this:

```
if ('https' === location.protocol) {
   port = 8443;
   protocol = 'wss://';
   isSecure = true;
}
```

I know that `a == b` is same as `b == a`, so why do people use `value == var` instead of `var == value`?

Is there a standard for this? And if yes, which is the standard way?

Comment: There is no standard way. Write whatever you find more readable. By the way, this style is called [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) "If https is the protocol, port 8443 you must use"

Comment: I'd say it's more common to be `var == value` as it's clearer from a readability standpoint, but it's ultimately the same thing so write it any way you want

Comment: I think that it's a fair question. In JAVA it was a way to avoid null pointer exceptions... http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/74093/7336

Comment: take a look here: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74086/if-constant-variable-vs-if-variable-constant

Comment: nice to know about yoda condition

Comment: possible duplicate of [(null != someVariable) OR (someVariable != null)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18048853/1048572) and many others

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are seeing is [yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

Yoda conditions describe the same expression, but reversed:

```
if ( 42 == $value ) { /* ... */ }
// Reads like: "If 42 equals the value..."
```

The advantage is

> Placing the constant value in the expression does not change the behavior of the program (unless the values evaluate to false—see below). In programming languages that use a single equals sign (=) for assignment and not for comparison, a possible mistake is to assign a value unintentionally instead of writing a conditional statement.

Note that it is clearly lack of readability. I personally don't prefer this way.